# jQuery get and post returning different results with await?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to get the headers from the server response after awaiting a jQuery post request.

```
var res = await $.post(GetUrl("/accounts"), JSON.stringify(acc));
```

will return only the body, while

```
var accs = await $.get(GetUrl("/accounts"));
```

will return an object from which I can get some headers (not all) and the body. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` uses `then` on the object it's given (somewhat indirectly). jQuery's `ajax` calls `then` callbacks with three arguments (whereas a normal promise calls `then` callbacks with exactly one argument). Because of that mis-match, you're only getting the *first* argument jQuery's `ajax` calls `then` with.

You can convert the return value (these are promises, they're a pipeline) so you get all three things that jQuery's `ajax` calls the callback with:

```
const [data, textStatus, jqXHR] =
    await $.post("/echo/html/", {html: "Hi there", delay: 1})
         .then((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => [data, textStatus, jqXHR]);
```

[Live Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17m6241d/)

This is only necessary because of jQuery's unusual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `$.post()` is to be a convenient shortcut. When you use it with `await`, you'll effectively get only the first parameter that would have been passed into the Promise resolution callback had you used traditional Promise coding:

```
$.post(GetUrl("/accounts"), JSON.stringify(acc))
  .then(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
    // ...
  });
```

You're only getting `data`. If you code it as above, then that third parameter will be your (jQuery extended) XHR object.

Note that your use of `$.get()` will mean that `accs` will be the promise returned, and you don't know that the operation has completed.